# Movie about a kid with superpowers who fights monsters, has a hamster-like friend who the enemy makes fall into a pit and become a monster

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw this movie with my dad when I was younger. I think it was a Japanese/Asian movie about a war of some kind. I remember there's like a kid who is the hero of the story. I think he has a super power of some kind. He has a friend who is like a hamster or a creature alike from another world or something. Together they are fighting monsters/robots from a world that looks like hell where it's full of fiery metals or something. Then I remember the hamster fell into a pit of lava of some kind as the enemy dropped him there and he was resurrected as one of the monsters and the kid had to fight him.

Does anyone know what movie this is?

Comment: Hey, welcome! Do you have any more details - when is "when you were younger"? Was it animated or live action? If animated, what style? How old did it seem? Was it on TV or in a theater? What language was it in? Where were you?

Answer (score 2):

The Great Yokai War

Trailer:

The power the kid has is as a Kirin rider.
The monster/robot hybrids are kikai, created by feeding Yokai into yomotsumono's fire. 
A sunekosuri is the little "hamster" that is transformed into a kikai by being thrown into the fire.